# Object is not persisting on save mongodb spring data java

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-mongodb

Hi i am implementing auditing in mongodb using spring data mongo
here is my audit class each model class extends that class

```
public abstract class Audit implements Auditable<String,String> {  
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id 
    private String id;  

    @Version  
    private Long version;  

    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    private DateTime createdDate;  

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lastModifiedBy;  

    @LastModifiedDate
    private DateTime lastModifiedDate;

    public boolean isNew() {  

        return id == null;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public DateTime getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(DateTime createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public String getLastModifiedBy() {
        return lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedBy(String lastModifiedBy) {
        this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public DateTime getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedDate(DateTime lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    }



}
```

So when i update any object and call the following function

```
//event is updated object
mongoTemplate.save(event);
```

On save i am implmenting ApplicationListener as follow so controls shifts to onApplicationEvent function

```
public class AuditingEventListner implements ApplicationListener<BeforeConvertEvent<Object>> {

    private AuditorAware<String> auditorAware;


    public AuditingEventListner(AuditorAware<String> auditorAware) {

        this.auditorAware = auditorAware;
    }

    public void onApplicationEvent(BeforeConvertEvent<Object> event) {

        Object obj = event.getSource();
        // this obj is not persisting as i am getting object from db before updating so it should have all the values pre populated but it other then new updated values are all coming as null and result into new object creation in DB
        if (Audit.class.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass())) {

            Audit entity = (Audit) obj;
            if (entity.isNew()) {

                entity.setCreatedBy(auditorAware.getCurrentAuditor());
                entity.setCreatedDate(new DateTime());
            }

            entity.setLastModifiedBy(auditorAware.getCurrentAuditor());
            entity.setLastModifiedDate(new DateTime());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my dao method that edit an event

```
public Event edit(Event event,String eventid) throws Exception,NotFoundException{

        logger.debug("Editing existing Event");

        Event existingEvent = null; 

        try {

            if(null != eventid && !eventid.equalsIgnoreCase("") ){

                existingEvent = get(eventid);
            }

            if(null ==existingEvent){

                throw new NotFoundException(eventid); 
            }

            if(null != event.getTitle() && !event.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            {
                existingEvent.setTitle(event.getTitle());
            }

            if(null != event.getDescription() && !event.getDescription().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            {
                existingEvent.setDescription(event.getDescription());
            }

            if(event.getOrganizationId()!=0){

                existingEvent.setOrganizationId(event.getOrganizationId());
            }

            if(event.getEventTypeId()!=0){

                existingEvent.setEventTypeId((event.getEventTypeId()));
            }

            if(null != event.getAddress1() && !event.getAddress1().equalsIgnoreCase("")){

                existingEvent.setAddress1(event.getAddress1());
            }

            if(null != event.getAddress2() && !event.getAddress2().equalsIgnoreCase("")){

                existingEvent.setAddress2(event.getAddress2());
            }

            if(null != event.getCity() && !event.getCity().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            {
                existingEvent.setCity(event.getCity());
            }

            if(null != event.getState() && !event.getState().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            {
                existingEvent.setState(event.getState());
            }

            if(null!= event.getCountry() && !event.getCountry().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            {
                existingEvent.setCountry(event.getCountry());
            }

            if(null != event.isMultiDate()){

                existingEvent.setMultiDate(event.isMultiDate());
            }

            if(null!=event.getLatitude() &&  event.getLatitude()!=0.0 && !event.getLatitude().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("") )
            {
                existingEvent.setLatitude(event.getLatitude());
            }

            if(null != event.getLongitude() && event.getLongitude() != 0.0 && !event.getLongitude().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")){

                existingEvent.setLongitude(event.getLongitude());
            }

            if(null != event.getLastModifiedBy() && !event.getLastModifiedBy().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            {           
                existingEvent.setLastModifiedBy(event.getLastModifiedBy());
            }

            if(null != event.getMultiLingual() && event.getMultiLingual().size() > 0 )
            {
                for(MultiLingual multiLingual:event.getMultiLingual())
                {
                    multiLingual.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

                }
                existingEvent.setMultiLingual(event.getMultiLingual());
            }

            if(null !=event.getTo() && !event.getTo().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            {
                existingEvent.setTo(event.getTo());
            }

            if(null !=event.getFrom() && !event.getFrom().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            {
                existingEvent.setFrom(event.getFrom());
            }

            //existingEvent.setLastModified(new Date());

            mongoTemplate.save(event);

            return event;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            logger.error("An error has occurred while trying to edit existing event", e);

            throw e;
        }

    }
```

So in onApplicationEvent the object is not pre populating. any idea how can i achieve that. ?i am getting object from db before updating as you can see in edit method so it should have all the values pre populated but other then new updated values are all coming as null and result into new object creation in DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem i was doing it wrong

```
 mongoTemplate.save(event);
```

I need to pass existingEvent object to save method instead of event so correction is

```
 mongoTemplate.save(existingEvent);
```